# Different results for git Merge and Rebase

Tags: git, android-studio, git-merge, git-rebase

Git merge and rebase aim is the same, rejoining two branches together in order to get a single up to date branch.

When trying the Merge and Rebase tool in Android Studio(which uses git commands obviously), I'm getting different results.

Merge - show me real conflicts between many files.

Rebase - Show only 1 conflicted file.

I know that merge and rebase are two completely different commands(rebase changes the HEAD of the feature branch, and adding the new commits on top of it(keeping commits history log) while merge tries to merge the HEADS of both branches). But it doesn't make sense that they return different results. I mean, conflict is a conflict no? If user A and user B changed the same line so it always should conflict that line, no matter if you use merge or rebase?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on how many commit you have after the branch-point.

If you have more than one commit, `git merge` will show you all conflicts at once and `git rebase` will show you the conflicts for each commit.

Supposing that you have this situation:

```
master    A --- B --- C   <- HEAD of master
             \
branch        --- D --- E <- HEAD of branch
```

If you are on `E` and you do a `git merge master`, git will show you all the conflicts and ask you to fix before to create the merge commit.

If you do a `git rebase master`, instead, git will take the head of master (`C`) then apply your commit `D` and show the conflicts (if presents) asking to fix and proceed with the rebase. When you fix the conflicts and amend the commit, you proceed with `git rebase --continue` and it will apply the commit `E` and again show you the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

**Think of a rebase as a merge in the opposite direction.**

If the direction is different, it's natural for the merge or rebase to stop at a different conflict.

(That's why you only see 1 conflict during rebase).

Results of rebase vs merge heavily depend on the actual changes. They should be the same if changes are independent between sets of commits.

But if any commit changes something that was changed by an earlier commit, then the order (merge vs rebase) can give different results/conflicts.

**Example**

If you e.g. remove a line of code and you rebase, and the last version of a file has the same surrounding lines, that line will likely be removed without issues.

All it takes is that it "applies cleanly", no matter what changed underneath.

But, if you merge and the code in the merged area changed, deleting the line may conflict with other changes (even if the "net result" of the merged commits is the same as the original you worked on).

**Workaround**

The best approach is to probably rebase interactively `git rebase -i master`. This way you can "influence" the order of changes in your rebase so that they apply cleanly or result in fewer conflicts.

Usually, you probably only want to use merge when you're integrating changes from multiple branches into a release. So both rebase and merge functionally have "different purposes". You rebase when you want to append your own local changes to a remote branch, and merge when you're picking and mixing changes other people have made.

Note that both merge and rebase are "cheating" - they change the timeline of commits and changes can have side effects depending on the order.

(E.g. if one person removes a line and then reverts the change ... while another just removes the line ... should the line be removed or not?)

So the order (rebase vs merge) matters.